# MaterialRangeBar: setOnRangeBarChangeListener method

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-view, ratingbar

I'm trying to implement an option in android app where users can use range-bar to set the radius of where they want the application to seek for nearby friends. For the range bar I'm using this library [GitHub page.](https://github.com/oli107/material-range-bar) Here is also the part of the .xml code for my range-bar from my activity.

```
<com.appyvet.materialrangebar.RangeBar
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:id="@+id/radiusRangeBar"
        app:mrb_rangeBar="false"
        app:mrb_tickStart="1"
        app:mrb_tickEnd="5"
        app:mrb_tickInterval="1"
        app:mrb_pinRadius="8dp"
        app:mrb_pinMaxFont="8sp"
        app:mrb_barWeight="1dp"
        app:mrb_tickColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:mrb_connectingLineColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:mrb_connectingLineWeight="3dp"
        app:mrb_pinColor="@color/switchColor"
        app:mrb_selectorColor="@color/switchColor"
        app:mrb_selectorSize="10dp"/>
```

What I want to do?

I want when the user try to move the selector to receive message. This is the function responsive for that.

```
RangeBar radiusRangeBar;
AlertDialog alertDialog;
AlertDialog.Builder builder;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_settings, container, false);
radiusRangeBar = (RangeBar) view.findViewById(R.id.radiusRangeBar);

radiusRangeBar.setOnRangeBarChangeListener(new RangeBar.OnRangeBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRangeChangeListener(RangeBar rangeBar, int leftPinIndex, int rightPinIndex, String leftPinValue, String rightPinValue) {
                builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                builder.setMessage("You are about to set the Nearby friends radius on " + rightPinValue + "km") ;
                builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        privateAccountsSwitch.setChecked(true);
                    }
                });
                builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        privateAccountsSwitch.setChecked(false);
                    }
                });
                alertDialog = builder.create();
                alertDialog.show();
            }
        });
}
```

What is wrong? 
- Since this was the only function mentioned in the documentation that from the GitHub page I tried to implement it but It's not appropriate for my setup because it displays message as I'm scrolling and I want that to happen only when I'll stop scrolling. 
Is that doable or I have to try another method to notify the user for his action.

Comment: you need to take textview and show it those range

Comment: Yeah I tried to but at this point I'd like to user to be able to confirm his action using the positive button from the Dialog.

Comment: then set that range inside of positiveListener onclick event

Comment: The Dialog is being created after every scroll so I don't think that your suggestion can be useful in my case thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I addition to the answer from [azizbekian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1083957/azizbekian).
I have updated my code and posted here so every person in future to be able to solve his problem quick and easy.

This is the `setOnRangeBarChangeListener` now.

```
 radiusRangeBar.setOnRangeBarChangeListener(new RangeBar.OnRangeBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRangeChangeListener(RangeBar rangeBar, int leftPinIndex, int rightPinIndex, String leftPinValue, String rightPinValue) {
            rangeBarValue = rightPinValue;
            // first remove the previous action if it exists
            handler.removeCallbacks(showDialogRunnable);
            // schedule a new action to take place in 700ms
            handler.postDelayed(showDialogRunnable, 700);
        }
    });
```

I've created string variable which initialized by moving the rangebar selector.

Then if no action is going on the `handler.postDelayed(showDialogRunnable, 700);`  will trigger;

Here is the code for this function as well.

```
private final Handler handler = new Handler();
final Runnable showDialogRunnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                builder.setMessage("You are about to set the Nearby friends radius on " + rangeBarValue + "km") ;
                builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        privateAccountsSwitch.setChecked(true);
                    }
                });
                builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        privateAccountsSwitch.setChecked(false);
                    }
                });
                alertDialog = builder.create();
                alertDialog.show();
                alertDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.alertDialogPositiveButton));
                alertDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.alertDialogNegativeButton));
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

I've inspected source code of the custom widget. There does not exist any callback, that you are interested in, which means, that you have two options: either change the sources itself, or apply a workaround.

I will share the solution for second approach.
Overall, you need some action to take place only in case when range has not been change for a while (let's specify that duration to be 300ms). Thus you can use `handler.postDelayed()` mechanism to overcome the problem.

Declare a `handler` and `showDialogRunnable` fields as such:

```
    private final Handler handler = new Handler();

    private final Runnable showDialogRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            showDialog();
        }
    }
```

Then perform following changes inside listener:

```
    radiusRangeBar.setOnRangeBarChangeListener(new RangeBar.OnRangeBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRangeChangeListener(RangeBar rangeBar, int leftPinIndex, int rightPinIndex, String leftPiString rightPinValue) {
            // first remove the previous action if it exists
            handler.removeCallbacks(showDialogRunnable);
            // schedule a new action to take place in 300ms
            handler.postDelayed(showDialogRunnable, 300);
        }
    });
```

This will ensure, that as soon as `onRangeChangeListener()` is not triggered in a window of 300ms, then dialog will be shown.

Comment: This is great you convinced me thanks a lot. I'll this right away.